# Changing UITabBarController More Item Colors

Tags: iphone, uitableview, colors, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with a "More" tab whose color scheme I would like to modify.

**Navigation Controller Nav Bar Colors**

I've been able to change the background color of the "More" tab's UINavigationController by subclassing the UITabBarController and adding the following code to the ViewDidLoad method:

```
UINavigationController *moreController = self.moreNavigationController;
moreController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I would also like to change the Nav controller's text color but have not been able to determine how to accomplish this.

**Table View Highlight Colors**

I'd like to disable or **change the highlight color** for the "More" tab's UITableView.  I don't want to disable the ability to select, I just want to change or remove the blue highlight color.

I see where I can change the SelectedTextColor property for a UITableViewCell's texLabel, but I'm unsure how or when this needs to be set given I'm not the table view's datasource.

**Edit View Nav Bar Color**

When the Edit button is selected, the nav bar at the top reverts to the basic blue color.

Is there any way to access this nav bar to change its tint color?

Comment: Have you tried to create a category to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've modified the "More" section in a `UITabBarController` is to simply push to a different `UITableView` instead and just create the cells I'm interested in that were displaying originally in the default "More" section.

All I do is just add a `UITabBarItem` with 3 dots that mimics the original "More" icon. That way you have complete control over the view.